# How to retrieve information from database and display in table?

Tags: php, formatting, html-table

This is my php code.

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $val) {
$_SESSION[$key]=$val;
}

mysql_connect('localhost', 'bikec_user', '4348@TxState');
mysql_select_db('bikecats_database');

$cnetid=$_POST['cnetid'];
$cpassword=$_POST['cpassword'];


$cnetid = stripslashes($cnetid);
$cpassword = stripslashes($cpassword);
$cnetid = mysql_real_escape_string($cnetid);
$cpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($cpassword);

$sql="SELECT RentalID, BikeID, RentalStartDate, RentalEndDate
  FROM rental  
  WHERE CustTxStateNetID = '$cnetid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$rentalid=$row['RentalID'];
$bikeid=$row['BikeID'];
?>
```

This is the html code. It should be displayihg the query that's been retrieved from the database but for some reason when I run it the table comes up blank. I know I'm only echoing two variables but even those come up empty.

```
        <div class="span9">  
          <h2>My Account</h2>
          <p><strong>My Rentals</strong></p>
        <table class="table table-striped">  
            <thead>  
              <tr>  
                <th>Rental ID</th>   
                <th>Bike ID  
                <th>Check-Out Date</th>  
                <th>Return Date</th>  
              </tr>  
            </thead>  
            <tbody>  
              <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $rentalid ?></td>    
                <td><?php echo $bikeid ?></td>   
                <td></td> 
                <td></td>  
              </tr>   
              <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td></td>   
                <td></td>   
                <td></td>  
              </tr>
            </tbody> 
        </table><br>
        </div><!-- end span -->
```

Comment: Use [tag:PDO] for your connection. `mysql_*` have been deprecated.

Comment: try var_dump($row) see what it is returning.. also use PDO

Comment: You need to confirm that the sql is returning results first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

---------------------------EDITED-----------------------------------------

```
<?php
   session_start();



  if(isset($_POST['cnetid'])){
  mysql_connect('localhost', 'bikec_user', '4348@TxState');
  mysql_select_db('bikecats_database');  
  $cnetid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cnetid']);
  $cpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cpassword']);
  $table = "<table class='table table-striped' >  
              <thead>  
                <tr>  
                  <th>Rental ID</th>   
                  <th>Bike ID  
                  <th>Check-Out Date</th>  
                  <th>Return Date</th>  
                </tr>  
              </thead>  
              <tbody>  
              ";
  $sql="SELECT RentalID, BikeID, RentalStartDate, RentalEndDate
    FROM rental  
    WHERE CustTxStateNetID = '$cnetid'";
    $body = "";
  $result=mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error());
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
     $body = $body." <tr><td>".$row['RentalID']."</td>  
                     <td>".$row['BikeID']."</td>   
                     <td>".$row['RentalStartDate']."</td> 
                     <td>".$row['RentalEndDate']."</td></tr> ";
   }
   $table = $table.$body."   
                <tr>  
                  <td></td>  
                  <td></td>   
                  <td></td>   
                  <td></td>  
                </tr>
              </tbody> 
          </table>" ;

  }
  else
  {
    $table = "No data..";
  }

  ?>


  <div class="span9">  
        <h2>My Account</h2>
        <p><strong>My Rentals</strong></p>
        <?php echo $table; ?>
        <br>
  </div>
```

PS: Error found, corrected, and code tested xD

Saludos ;)

Comment: I tried the new code but I'm getting an error on the php code:     while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
   $body = $body."  <tr>   <td>$row['RentalID']></td>  
                   <td>$row['BikeID']</td>   
                   <td>$row['RentalStartDate']</td> 
                   <td>$row['RentalEndDate']</td></tr> ";
 }                                                                  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in